# Typescript: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I don't understand why I'm getting this error for the code below.

> Typescript: Property 'size' does not exist on type 'never'

The error is pointing to `friendRef.size`.

It is also giving an error on `friendRef.update`:

> Property 'update' does not exist on type 'never'

How do I properly run a `WHERE` clause query on a collection that will only ever return either 1 or 0 records and then update some of its properties?

```
export const onRespondedToFriendRequest = functions.firestore
  .document("users/{userDocID}/notifications/{notifID}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const notifID = context.params.notifID;
    const uid = context.params.userDocID; // user A
    const beforeData = change.before.data();
    const afterData = change.after.data();
    const friendUID = afterData.uid; // user B (the friend)

    // If notifID is "2" and moveOnToNextStep = true
    if (notifID === "2" && afterData.moveOnToNextStep) {
      const friendsQuerySnapshot = await fs
        .collection("users/" + friendUID + "/friends")
        .where("uid", "==", uid)
        .limit(1)
        .get();

      let friendRef;

      friendsQuerySnapshot.forEach((friendDoc) => {
        friendRef = friendDoc.ref;        
      });

      if (friendRef && friendRef.size !== 0) { // ERROR HERE
        
        await friendRef.update({ // ERROR HERE
          stat: "1",
          modifiedDate: Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000).toString(),
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't handle the case where there are no results. In that case `friendRef` will be `undefined` (its default value), and you can't call `size` or `update` on that.

The simplest fix is to check for an empty result first, and only then have the rest of your code:

```
const friendsQuerySnapshot = await fs
  .collection("users/" + friendUID + "/friends")
  .where("uid", "==", uid)
  .limit(1)
  .get();

if (!friendsQuerySnapshot.empty) {
  let friendRef;

  friendsQuerySnapshot.forEach((friendDoc) => {
    friendRef = friendDoc.ref;        
  });

  if (friendRef) {
    await friendRef.update({
      stat: "1",
      modifiedDate: Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000).toString(),
    });
  }
}
```

At this point you actually also don't need the loop anymore, and can just do:

```
const friendsQuerySnapshot = await fs
  .collection("users/" + friendUID + "/friends")
  .where("uid", "==", uid)
  .limit(1)
  .get();

if (!friendsQuerySnapshot.empty) {
  const friendRef = friendsQuerySnapshot.docs[0].ref;

  await friendRef.update({
    stat: "1",
    modifiedDate: Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000).toString(),
  });
}
```

Comment: The 2nd code block gives the error: `Property 'update' does not exist on type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>'.ts(2339)`

Comment: The 1st code block gives the error: `Property 'update' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)`

Comment: `friendsQuerySnapshot.docs[0]` should be `friendsQuerySnapshot.docs[0].ref` if you are extracting the `DocumentReference` like OP is.

Comment: Good catch both!  --  I missed a `.ref` in the second codeblock. Added that just now.

Answer (score 0):

set type for `friendRef`:

```
let friendRef: Parameters<typeof friendsQuerySnapshot.forEach>[0]
```